git diff - show only the part of the line which is different, not entire line
I have a big single line .json files. How to use git diff to display only the part of the line that changed.
Lots of answers cover how to display changes, but this still prints entire line, and just applies different color to changed parts. I need to display changed parts only (maybe few char of context), and to omit exact matches entirely.
Example:
long line all same content except one.
long line all same content excluding one.

need something like:
-except+excluding

no context, because lines are huge


https://stackoverflow.com/a/64757454/7976758 git diff --word-diff=porcelain filename | grep '^[~+-]' Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-diff%5D+long+lines

@phd Aw shoot, searched for duplicates at start but didn't find this one.

To work nicely with .json i used git diff --word-diff-regex='[^[:space:],]+' + one of the variations with grep and porcelain or sed.

Tested some more examples, this is the best for .json:
git diff --word-diff-regex='[^[:space:],]+' --word-diff=porcelain | grep '^[~+-]'

Now if someone knows how to preserve syntax coloring with grep, this would be epic.

We have the --word-diff option for git diff. Doc here.

Example (classic diff)
- long line all same content except one
+ long line all same content excluding one

Same with --word-diff
long line all same content [-except-]{+excluding+} one

So I guess your -except+excluding target is just one pipe to sed away:
<your diff> | sed -Er "s/.*\[(\-[^-]+)\-\]\{(\+[^\+]+)\+\}.*/\1\2/"


I also like --color-words.

Tried that, it will still print entire line that changed.

On the other hand, maybe this is the solution, i just need to find how to grep colorized text.

Grepping /\{\+.*\+\}/ (or maybe just /\{\+/) might be easier than grepping colors, though.

Sed solution is great, I made one with grep but this is better. I guess only a way to preserve syntax color with grep / sed is missing but that would be just a sugar on a top. Thx for the help!

Recently I also implemented this which conditionally do line based diffs or character based diffs based on how much changes in the lines and maybe you can use the algorithm from it too, so I just share it in case git diff --word-diff wouldn't be enough.
DiffLib.jl
I guess I should extend it with more documentations later on. Let me know how to improve!
